# Accessing "this" in Function.prototype not possible?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to extend the function prototype to return a singleton version of a function.

```
Function.prototype.once = function() { 
  var called = false, memo; 
  return function() { 
        console.log('AP', this); 
        if (!called) memo = this.apply(this, arguments); 
        called = true; 
        return memo; 
  } 
}
```

The console logs the window object. Why is this != current function? And how to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't "close over" `this`, so you need to either resort to the old `var self = this` trick (ie, obtain a reference to `this` in a variable which *can* be closed over) or simply bind your function:

```
return function() { 
    console.log('AP', this); 
    if (!called) memo = this.apply(this, arguments); 
    called = true; 
    return memo; 
}.bind(this);
```

Comment: `bind` is the right approach. I will accept your answer. Sorry, @Florent, but meagar was 1 sec faster than you :)

Comment: IMHO, `.bind` is overkill, and should only be used if you do not control the scope of the function being called (such that you can close over outer-scoped variables).  When writing a plain nested function then a simple closure over an alias is more effective.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, it's possible, but your inner function creates a new context so the `this` inside it is not the same as the `this` outside.

Just create an external reference to the original function:

```
Function.prototype.once = function() {
    var f = this;   // use 'f' in the inner function
     ...
}
```

NB: depending on your intent you may also have the same issue with `arguments`.

Comment: You are right. Why haven't I though of this. But I like the approach with `bind` more :)

Comment: @BarthZalewski and how do you think `.bind` works?  ;-)   Also, `.bind` has the overhead of creating one more extra `function` than just closing over an extra reference to `this`.

Comment: (for more info, look at the polyfill at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind see just how much overhead `.bind` has)

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind to context on the anonymous function.

```
Function.prototype.once = function() { 
  var called = false, memo; 
  return (function() { 
    console.log('AP', this); 
    if (!called) memo = this.apply(this, arguments); 
    called = true; 
    return memo; 
  }).bind(this);
}
```